# DSUM in Access query yields Nulls in random records

Tags: ms-access, subquery, ms-access-2010

I have a query (in MS Access 2013) that gives me the Sales for various Items by Date, for each day for the next 12mo.  In another table, I have each Item with its known purchasing leadtime, say between 30 and 90 days.
I created a query, and for each Item, I calculated the future date according to the leadtime, using:

```
FutureDate: DateAdd("d",[Leadtime],Date())
```

I validated all Items exist in the Sales query, and all FutureDates are within the records that exist in Sales.

I need to calculate the sum of daily Sales between now and the calculated [FutureDate] for each Item, to get the total amount of Sales expected within the unique Leadtime of each item.

I tried function DSUM() with weird results:

The query of daily Sales already excludes any past sales, so my first try was:

```
TotalSalesInLeadtime: DSUM("DailySales","Sales","[DayOfSale]<=#" & [FutureDate] & "# AND [Item]='" & [SearchedItem] &"'")
```

For some Items, [TotalSalesInLeadtime] calculated correctly, while others evaluated to Null.

Then I tried:

```
TotalSalesInLeadtime: DSUM("DailySales","Sales","[DayOfSale] BETWEEN #" Date() "# AND #" & [FutureDate] & " AND [Item]='" & [SearchedItem] &"'")
```

The results now were reversed.  [TotalSalesInLeadtime] values now showed correctly for the items that previously showed Null, and were Null for items that previously evaluated correctly.

I never figured out why DSUM() did this.

To work around the DSUM() glitch, I went with an embedded subquery, which yielded all the values correctly, albeit at a significant performance hit:

```
SELECT [PurchItem],
        (SELECT Sum([DailySales]) AS SumOfSales
         FROM [Sales] 
         WHERE ([Item]=[LeadtimeItems].[PurchItem]) AND ([DayOfSale] Between Date() AND [LeadtimeItems].[FutureDate]))
        As TotalSalesInLeadtime
FROM LeadtimeItems
```

If anyone has a clue why DSUM may behave this way, I'd appreciate the help.  DSUM, when it works, certainly seems to go faster.

Comment: Your machine wouldn't happen to be using a `dd/mm/yyyy` date format, would it?

Comment: Yes, the database uses dd/mm/yyyy format.  You're on to something, I figure?

Answer (score 1):

When "gluing together" SQL statements (or fragments) that include date literals enclosed in hash marks (`#`), one must bear in mind that Access SQL and VBA will always interpret ambiguous date literals as `mm-dd-yyyy` regardless of the system-wide date format. So on a machine where Windows has been configured to use `dd-mm-yyyy`, an unambiguous date like April 30 will work okay

```
?DateSerial(2013,4,30)
30-04-2013 
?"#" & DateSerial(2013,4,30) & "#"
#30-04-2013#
?Eval("#" & DateSerial(2013,4,30) & "#")
30-04-2013
```

...but for the next day, May 1, things don't work so well

```
?DateSerial(2013,5,1)
01-05-2013 
?"#" & DateSerial(2013,5,1) & "#"
#01-05-2013#
?Eval("#" & DateSerial(2013,5,1) & "#")
05-01-2013
```

So the lesson is that any time we "glue together" date literals we *must* ensure that those dates are in an unambiguous format like `yyyy-mm-dd`. With regard to this particular question, we need to use

```
TotalSalesInLeadtime: DSUM("DailySales","Sales","[DayOfSale]<=#" & Format([FutureDate], "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# AND [Item]='" & [SearchedItem] &"'")
```

Comment: Going with `yyyy-mm-dd` did yield results in every row.  However, when I compare the results from the subquery approach with that of DSum(), the recordcount for query with DSum is exactly one record less.  I copy/pasted the results, found the missing record.  If I apply a filter to the Dsum query using the Access interface, the record is found.  when I re-query, still the recordcount is short by one.  Copy-Paste for static compare, and I find a different record is missing...filtering for it finds the record.  Some other failure mode is at work here.  I stuck with the subquery approach.