# Invalid datetime format exception from Access ODBC Driver

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datetime

I have some .NET code that reads from an ODBC driver (the driver is selected based on a DSN string (with username and password)) that reads several fields from a table, one of which fields is a DateTime field. The code works 100% of the time with SQL Server databases/ODBC drivers and most of the time with MS Access databases. However, sometimes I will get an "Invalid datetime format on column number 2 (DateTimeColumn)" exception on a particular row without even accessing that column directly (for example, even if I just call

```
reader.IsDBNull(someOtherColumn)
```

I still get the exception.

This seems to mostly (only?) happen when the Access database has been populated with data from Excel where some of the DateTimes were calculated (e.g. adding 1/24 to a datetime to get the next hour).

The exception goes away if I run the following query:

```
UPDATE MyTable Set DateTimeColumn = CDate(CStr(DateTimeColumn))
```

Thus, it would appear that there is some kind of rounding error involved from Excel's calculation of datetimes to the Access driver's calculation of datetimes.

Since some of this data is being provided by users who created their own database, I won't be able to run UPDATE queries on their database with my code. One potential Access-only workaround would be to call CDate(CStr(DateTimeColumn)) in my SQL statement, but that won't work for SQL Server or other databases.

I have tested this only with the 32-bit MS Access driver (I don't have the 64-bit drivers on my machine to test them) that works with both .mdb files and .accdb files, and the problem occurs regardless of whether the data is in a .mdb file or a .accdb file.

Edit:

For future reference, the `Date/Time` value in the Access database that was causing the Exception was `0x40E4277FFFFFFFF8` which in decimal is

41275.9999999999417923390865326

Also of possible interest is that while this value caused an error when trying to read the row via an `OdbcConnection`, reading the same row using an `OleDbConnection` did *not* throw an exception.

Comment: Can you isolate a record with a date value that causes the exception, copy that to a separate Access database file, and then make that file available for download (e.g., via wikisend.com, or similar)? I just spent a few minutes hacking an .accdb file with a hex editor trying to create "weird" date values but ACE ODBC didn't complain about any of them.

Comment: Gord, thank you for your time. Let me know if you are able to access the link in the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following workaround seems to work given the test data from the updated question.. It checks the `.Driver` property of the open connection to see if it is reading from an Access database. If so, it retrieves the `Date/Time` value as `Double` and then converts it back to `System.DateTime`. Otherwise, it just retrieves the `datetime` from SQL Server normally.

(Please note that this particular approach – using `rdr[0]) * 86400` – **will not** work correctly for `Date/Time` values in Access that are earlier than `1899-12-30 00:00:00`, i.e., when the `Double` value is negative.)

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace odbcTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection())
            {
                //con.ConnectionString =
                //        @"Driver={SQL Server};" +
                //        @"Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                //        @"Database=myDb;" +
                //        @"Trusted_connection=yes;";
                con.ConnectionString =
                        @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
                        @"Dbq=C:\__tmp\dateTest\TestSqlRead.accdb;";
                con.Open();
                using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand())
                {
                    DateTime dtm;
                    var accessTime0 = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
                    bool fromAccess = (con.Driver == "ACEODBC.DLL");
                    cmd.Connection=con;
                    if (fromAccess)
                        //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DateTimeCol FROM MyTable";  // this fails
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT {fn CDbl(DateTimeCol)} FROM MyTable";
                    else
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sqlDate FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1";
                    OdbcDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    rdr.Read();
                    if (fromAccess)
                        dtm = accessTime0.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(rdr[0]) * 86400);
                    else
                        dtm = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(dtm.ToString());
                    rdr.Close();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using con.Driver (or con.DataSource == "ACCESS") was my initial thought, but I was concerned that the ACEODBC.DLL string might change with access driver versions (would the 64-bit driver have the same .dll?)
Did you choose CDbl() rather than the CDate(CStr()) for performance? I was concerned that if there was a rounding issue copying from Excel to Access, then AddSeconds() might give me just before midnight when I thought I was getting the next day.

Comment: @user3000697 Yes, the DLL is named `ACEODBC.DLL` on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms. The name *could* change, but I doubt that it will. I chose `CDbl()` because Access stores dates internally as `Double` numbers. `CDate(CStr())` is risky because on machines whose default date format is `dd-mm-yyyy` it could potentially mangle ambiguous dates, e.g., April 2 might mysteriously become February 4. As for rounding error, once you have the `Double` value (without your code blowing up) you can fiddle with it as required; I just used `.AddSeconds()` because it was the most straightforward approach.

Comment: Are CDate() and CStr() really not reciprocal for MS Access? That's scary - I would have assumed that converting one direction would convert back the other direction safely. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jeremy Since the very beginning Jet/ACE has *always* interpreted ambiguous date literals as `mm-dd-yyyy` regardless of the Regional Settings on the machine itself. For an example, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19444274/2144390).

Comment: If I want to be able to use the same OdbcDataReader code and only use different SELECT statements (thus only have one "if(fromAccess)"), do you see any problem with the following query:

SELECT CDate(Round(CDbl(DateTimeCol),8))

(I don't care about time resolution less than a hundredth of a second)

That seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: @Jeremy Access `Date/Time` values only support resolution to the whole second anyway, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are none.

Access uses its own date format

```
'#2011-12-16#'
```

SQL-Server uses the ISO standard for date values:

```
20111216
```

And

```
2012-12-16THH:mm:ss.fff
```

for datetime

What you can do is fetch the table with the date values as string into a System.Data.DataTable, correct the values, and them write them back using update. Even better, never use text fields to store date/datetime, and you never have this problem in the first place, because it doesn't let you insert invalid datetime values (well, maybe Access does...).

Also, if you'd use parametrized queries for inserts, you wouldn't have this problem in the first place.

If you get an Excel file from the customer, you need to validate if the date values in the Excel sheet are valid. 
If not, somebody needs to correct the data in the Excel file.

- Date must always mach the same format (MM-DD-YYYY) and may not sometimes be (dd.MM.yyyy)
- Date must be > min value, like 01.01.1753 in SQL-Server (especially critical because of dates in format MM-DD-YY)
- Date may not exceed 31.12.9999 23:59:59.995 in SQL-Server

If you use access + SQL Server, the min date value must be then MAXIMUM of the two minimum date values, the max date value must be the minimum of the two maximum date values.

Comment: Am I misreading your answer, or do most of your comments seem to assume I'm storing the DateTime as a string, rather than a DateTime? 

Your suggestion about using a parameterized query is good, but I didn't think that .mdb files support parameterized queries -- would a view (saved query in Access) be just as good?

Comment: @user3000697 Yes, you can run a parameterized query against an ACE/Jet (Access) database. Saved queries in Access can serve as parameter queries, but that is only really useful when using DAO. For ODBC under .NET just use an `OdbcCommand` object and give it some `.Parameter`s. There are lots of examples around here showing how to do it with `OleDbCommand` objects, and `OdbcCommand` objects work the same way.

Comment: Sorry - I was confusing parameterized query (which I have used with Access) with stored procedures, thinking that Quandary was suggesting to use a stored procedure to handle the inconsistent formats for the DateTime strings