# pyodbc import error because of Invalid Datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I´ve already look it up here, but couldn´t find a solution for my problem. I want to get a dataframe from 4 accces databanks and 2 work with this exact code and the other 2 display this error:

```
DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC-Treiber für Microsoft Access]Ungültiges Datetime-Format. bei Spaltennummer 11 (dtime) (35) (SQLGetData)')
```

the Data is in each data bank the same in terms of format. See my code below:

```
    conn_str = (
r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
r'DBQ=C:\Users\hoho11.DE\Documents\WLTP_Datenbank\Database_JRC2_SE_UK.accdb;')

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

cursor = conn.cursor()

for table_info in cursor.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
    print(table_info.table_name)
```

and the error comes here:

```
df_3 = pd.read_sql_query(sql='SELECT * FROM TB_cycles_car', con=conn)
df_3.head()
```

many thanks in advance for your support!!

Comment: Can you provide a download link for a small sample database that can be used to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to confirm that the table you are trying to read is a normal local Access table, not a view or a linked table connected to some other file format (e.g., an Excel spreadsheet or a CSV file).

Comment: I´ve produced a small amount with 5.000 lines, but the Problem is that the code worked with it. It just don´t work with the hole accdb. I´ve tried to import the accdb to another accdb, but the error stays the same. I´m really confused.

Comment: If I delete the 'dtime' Column in the accdb table the code works as well @GordThompson

Comment: Do you get an error if you do `rows = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TB_cycles_car").fetchall()` …?

Comment: @GordThompson the same DataError 22007 appears :(

Comment: Possibly related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20133229/2144390).

Comment: I solved it, thanks a lot @GordThompson :):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally find the answer. I selected the Error showing column and import it as a string. I just wrote:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql='SELECT ID, ..., Cstr(dtime), dates FROM TB_cycles_car', con=conn)
```

The DataError didn´t show up anymore :)
Thanks a lot @GordThompson for helping!