# "Invalid datetime format" reading MS Access date/time values with .read_sql()

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

The ODBC to python type bindings are causing a problem when trying to read an old access .mdb

There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133229/invalid-datetime-format-exception-from-access-odbc-driver), but I can't get it to work in python.

I'm using this to read my .mdb

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import pyodbc

##Source Conn
def get_source_conn():
    driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
    path = r'//SERVER/database.mdb'
    assert os.path.exists(path)

    return pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, dbq=path, CHARSET='UTF8')

def safeRead(sql):
    try:
        conn = get_source_conn()
        conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
        conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
        # conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_TYPE_DATE, encoding='utf-8')
   
        df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
    finally:
        try:
            conn.close()
        except:
            pass
    return df
    
class InventoryTransaction():

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        return safeRead('SELECT * FROM [INVENTORY TRANSACTIONS]')

dfTransactionTarget = InventoryTransaction.all()
```

The above produces this error:

```
DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid datetime format on column number 2 (TransactionDate) (35) (SQLGetData)')
```

If I uncomment my type binding to try and convert SQL_TYPE_DATE to a string, I get:

```
ValueError: Invalid sqltype 91.  Must be SQL_CHAR or SQL_WCHAR or SQL_WMETADATA
```

If I could just get the results of ODBC entirely as strings I could also do all the type coercing myself, as the data in question isn't that large of a set.

How do I successfully read this data?

****Additional Info Based on @GordThompson 's advice** **

1. CStr does not seem to handle NULLS

```
((
    "SELECT "
    "[TransactionID], "
    "CStr([TransactionDate]) AS someCol, "
    "[ProductID] "
    "FROM [INVENTORY TRANSACTIONS] "
    # "WHERE ISNULL([TransactionDate]) = 0 "
))
```

Output:

```
DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid use of Null (-3030) (SQLGetData)')
```

2. Even if I filter out nulls I don't get something that I can use:

```
((
    "SELECT "
    "[TransactionID], "
    "CStr([TransactionDate]) AS someCol, "
    "[ProductID] "
    "FROM [INVENTORY TRANSACTIONS] "
    "WHERE [TransactionDate] IS NULL "
))
```

Output:

```
DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid use of Null (-3030) (SQLGetData)')
#(same error)
```

3. If I try something more complex:

```
((
    "SELECT "
    "[TransactionID], "
    "IIF(ISNULL([TransactionDate]), '', CStr([TransactionDate])) AS someCol, "
    "[ProductID] "
    "FROM [INVENTORY TRANSACTIONS] "
    "WHERE [TransactionDate] IS NULL "
))
```

Output:

```
DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid procedure call (-3030) (SQLGetData)')
```

Comment: @Parfait, I'm aware of SELECT *'s downsides, but its not really relevant with such a small data set. That said, if there is some special circumstance for this with access, I would not be aware of that.  I'm trying to go through the data right now to find the problem conversions, and will try to post them ASAP

Comment: @Parfait - Upon further reflection I'm not sure seeing the data would help us.  It would halve to be extracted through access's export to CSV interface and therefore already transformed into a string.  All we'll end up with are strings formatted as 'mm/dd/YYYY' and nulls

Comment: Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63848699/2144390). TL;DR – Try using `pd.read_sql_query("SELECT CStr(TransactionDate) AS TranDateStr, … FROM [INVENTORY TRANSACTIONS]", conn)`

Comment: Also, Access ODBC does not use `utf-8` encoding. The default pyodbc encoding (UTF-16LE) is the correct one.

Comment: @GordThompson - As always your advice is sage, however it didn't seem to get me us all the way there.  I've gotten past the initial error and thrown the kitchen sink at it all morning, but so far haven't been able to return data.  I've updated the question to reflect new information from my attempts, and have changed the encoding as you suggest.  Any more ideas would be great.

Comment: `IIf(IsNull(…` [works for me](https://pastebin.com/p9tVFC6a) using the ACE driver `{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`